# `near '(': syntax error` creating a view for bestselling album in each genre with sales

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, group-by, count

This code uses the Chinook database to create a view called BestSeller for the bestselling album in each genre with sales (based on the quantity of tracks sold) with the columns Genre, Album, Artist, and Sales.

```
CREATE VIEW vBestSellingGenreAlbum AS SELECT DISTINCT 
   g.Name Genre, 
   FIRST_VALUE(a.Title) OVER (PARTITION BY g.GenreId ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) Album, 
   FIRST_VALUE(r.Name) OVER (PARTITION BY g.GenreId ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) Artist, 
   MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY g.GenreId) Sales
FROM genres g
INNER JOIN tracks t ON t.GenreId = g.GenreId
INNER JOIN albums a ON a.AlbumId = t.AlbumId
INNER JOIN artists r ON r.ArtistId = a.ArtistId
INNER JOIN invoice_items i ON i.TrackId = t.TrackId
GROUP BY g.GenreId, a.AlbumId;
SELECT * FROM vBestSellingGenreAlbum;
```

I get the error

```
near '(': syntax error
```

Comment: Probably you are using an old version of SQLite (before 3.25.0) that does not support window functions.

Comment: It works just fine on my machine (given suitable definitions of the tables involved).  So I agree with @forpas that you're using an older version of SQLite before `FIRST_VALUE` was a thing.  What does `SELECT sqlite_version();` give you?

Comment: @dan04 it gives me 3.7.17 but this is the version my uni has given me and the version they will mark our work on.

Comment: The window functions ("partition by" here) were [added in 3.25.0](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html).  If you really need to use a version that's over eight years old, you'll need to simplify your query quite a bit.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Could you spot the exact position throwing the problem by removing parts?

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. [Help]

Answer (score 4):

For versions of SQLite prior to 3.25.0, you can do it with 2 levels of aggregation and by utilizing SQLite's feature of [bare columns](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bare_columns_in_an_aggregate_query):

```
SELECT Genre, Album, Artist, MAX(Sales) Sales
FROM (
  SELECT g.Name Genre, 
         a.Title Album, 
         r.Name Artist, 
         COUNT(*) Sales
  FROM genres g
  INNER JOIN tracks t ON t.GenreId = g.GenreId
  INNER JOIN albums a ON a.AlbumId = t.AlbumId
  INNER JOIN artists r ON r.ArtistId = a.ArtistId
  INNER JOIN invoice_items i ON i.TrackId = t.TrackId
  GROUP BY g.GenreId, a.AlbumId
)
GROUP BY Genre;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ky29Zexatii1HcQbtuJ5j6/0).

Comment: I had never heard of this feature, so the query looked invalid to me, and all that came to mind was old MySQL versions picking arbirary values in such situations instead of raising an error. Interesting that SQLite really returns the best selling album here. A great feature in times window functions were not available.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux, check your LD_LIBRARY_PATH for sqlite lib > 3.25.
More than one version of sqlite may be installed in your system.  Ensure
that the recent version ( >3.25)  has precedence in LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How does checking that resolve the given problem?